# How to dynamically target the different FileMaker applications

Tags: macos, applescript, filemaker

I'm writing a system-wide Service that accept the currently selected text and does various searches in our internal FileMaker database.

I've written something that works fine on my dev machine, where FileMaker exists as "FileMaker Pro Advanced". Now I can't get it to work on the others machines where the non-developer version of FileMaker ("FileMaker Pro") is installed.

The issue is that when the script runs in one of the client machines, I get the "Where is *foo*" dialog (I'd say) because of the "using terms" line, and I don't want that. Is it possible to target FileMaker so that I can compile my script and run it on my clients ?

Here's what I currently have :

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set _target to null

    try
        tell application "Finder" to get name of application "FileMaker Pro Advanced"

        set _target to application "FileMaker Pro Advanced"
    end try
    if _target is null then
        try
            tell application "Finder" to get name of application "FileMaker Pro"

            set _target to application "FileMaker Pro"
        end try
    end if
    if _target is null then
        display alert "FileMaker cannot be found"
        return
    end if

    using terms of "FileMaker Pro Advanced"
        tell _target
            -- script goes here
        end tell
    end using terms of
end run
```

Comment: Is the bundle id the same on both FMP and FMPA? If so, just use that instead of mucking about with app names. e.g. `tell application id "com.filemaker.whatever" ...`

Comment: Also, sympathies on the FileMaker dog chain, that crap is just evil. You couldn't just get IT to set you up a common-or-garden Linux server with PostgreSQL on it and point everyone at that?

Comment: FMPA12 bundle ID is "com.filemaker.client.advanced12" and I won't bother to go check the normal version because meh, really, *12* ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can expect the end user's installation of FileMaker to be in the standard place, the following should work:

```
set _fmpa to "/Applications/FileMaker/FileMaker Pro Advanced.app"
set _fmp to "/Applications/FileMaker/FileMaker Pro.app"

try
    tell application _fmpa to launch
    set _target to _fmpa
end try

try
    tell application _fmp to launch
    set _target to _fmp
end try

tell application _target
    ...
end tell
```

Comment: (This also applies to @brian_schick's answer below). The thing is that I can't compile the AppleScript with a dynamic _target, because then FM terminology isn't available and it fails to recognize things like "current layout". So I wrap that into an `using terms from` but then I get the dialog at runtime on machines where FMPA isn't installed.

Comment: Have you tried eliminating `using terms from` completely? Keep everything the same as above, except the final `tell` is to `"FileMaker Pro Advanced"` on your system. Change it to `_target`, then deliver it. A quick test on my system using this technique showed that to work. You don't need `user terms` on your system or theirs. The script is compiled by the time it gets to their system, so there's no compilation error either.

Comment: @tiennou: The 'using terms from' block kicks in during compilation. I'm guessing the problem is that Automator's 'Run AppleScript' action stores your script in source code, not compiled, form. (Yeah, Automator's pretty brainless too.) If you're the only one with FMPA, you could try renaming it to FMP, then compile against that using standard, AS-compiler-friendly `tell app "FileMaker Pro"` blocks. Fingers crossed if the apps' filenames are identical, AS won't care which one it actually is.

Comment: The other option would be write your script using raw AE codes (`«class docu»`, `«event ascrgetd»`, etc), avoiding the need for compile-time terminology. That'll let you use dynamic targets however you like. IIRC [Satimage's Smile editor](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/index.html) has a menu option for copy-pasting AS source code converting keywords to raw AE codes. Decompiling the script on a machine that doesn't have FM* installed will also do it; just pick Chess.app when the "Where is FileMaker*?" prompt appears, then change `tell app "Chess.app"` to `tell app _target` and use that.

Comment: I'll admit one more thought. Generally, when dealing with this convoluted of a workaround, it's time to take a step back and re-evaluate the approach. Your original question mentioned that this is a service that's taking selected text and doing something with it in FileMaker. Think of another approach. Perhaps instead of controlling FileMaker with AppleScript, use the `fmp` URL scheme to run a script that does the heavy lifting. Check out http://www.filemaker.com/help/12/fmp/html/sharing_data.16.7.html.

Answer (score -1):

How about a simple initial test like this:

```
try
  if exists application "FileMaker Pro Advanced" then
    set _target to "FileMaker Pro Advanced"
  else if exists application "FileMaker Pro" then
    set _target to "FileMaker Pro"
  else
    <handle error>
  end if
end try
```